# Apache Flink: ProcessWindowFunction is not applicable

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I want to use a `ProcessWindowFunction` in my Apache Flink project. But I am getting some error when using process function, see below code snippet

The error is:

> The method process(ProcessWindowFunction,R,Tuple,TimeWindow>) in the type WindowedStream,Tuple,TimeWindow> is not applicable for the arguments (JDBCExample.MyProcessWindows)

My program:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> inputStream;

inputStream = env.addSource(new JsonArraySource());

inputStream.keyBy(0)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(10)))
  .process(new MyProcessWindows());
```

My `ProcessWindowFunction`:

```
private class MyProcessWindows 
  extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, String>, String, Window>
{

  public void process(
      String key, 
      Context context, 
      Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> input, 
      Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception 
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: can you double check the error message? It seem as if there is something missing in the signature of the `process()` method.

Answer (score 5):

The problem are probably the generic types of the `ProcessWindowFunction`.

You are referencing the key by position (`keyBy(0)`). Therefore, the compiler cannot infer its type (`String`) and you need to change the `ProcessWindowFunction` to:

```
private class MyProcessWindows 
    extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple, Window>
```

By replacing `String` by `Tuple` you have now a generic placeholder for keys that you can cast to `Tuple1<String>` when you need to access the key in the `processElement()` method:

```
public void process(
    Tuple key, 
    Context context, 
    Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> input, 
    Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) throws Exception {

  String sKey = (String)((Tuple1)key).f0;
  ...
}
```

You can avoid the cast and use the proper type if you define a `KeySelector<IN, KEY>` function to extract the key, because the return type `KEY` of the `KeySelector` is known to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Fabian, I replaced String by Tuple but still the same error persists. Do I need to define the KeySelector function too. Is it mandatory?? Also simple window operation like apply is also throwing the same error whereas reduce is working properly.

Answer (score 3):

What Fabian said :) Using `Tuple` should work, but does involve some ugly type casts in your `ProcessWindowFunction`. Using a `KeySelector` is easy and results in cleaner code. E.g.

```
.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<String,JsonObject>, String>() {

    @Override
    public String getKey(Tuple2<String, JsonObject> in) throws Exception {
        return in.f0;
    }
})
```

The above then lets you define a `ProcessWindowFunction` like:

```
public class MyProcessWindows extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JsonObject>, Tuple2<String, String>, String, TimeWindow> {
```